# add_rewrite_rule for woocommerce filter_ is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, woocommerce, url-rewriting

I am trying to get the product list with some category and attribute.
Dirrect link working well but custom_rewrite_rules not working as expected. Yes, I reload permalinks in admin panel.
Please help to find solution. Woocommerce products list.

If I open index.php?product_cat=oil&filter_flavor=mint filter for category and product attribute will work as expected but when i will try localhost/shop/oil/mint i get products filtered by category only but missed filter_flavor

```php
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&filter_flavor=mint', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for this task is pretty simple. You can turn on "Enable Archives?" checkbox and save for some attribute in "Products->Attributes" from wp admin panel. Then you can get it by link `index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&pa_flavor=mint` now rewrite rules from my question will work with this fixed url.